# DB optimization

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have problems with my DB proceses

I runn an website developed using angular, typescript and laravel

Script demo: https://codecanyon.net/item/mtdb-ultimate-movietv-database/6447206

Script documentation: https://support.vebto.com/help-center/categories/35/mtdb-ultimate-movieandtv-database

**Server:**
Processor: Intel 2x Xeon Silver 4214 - 24 c / 48 t - 2.2 GHz / 3.2 GHz

Memory: 96GB DDR4 ECC 2400MHz

Storage: 2x960GB SSD NVMe Soft RAID 1

PHP 7.3 fcgi

**mysql - MariaBD 10.3:**

```
    [mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server188.com.err
performance-schema=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
local-infile=0
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 268435456
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
max_connections = 1000
max_user_connections = 500
wait_timeout = 28800
connect_timeout = 10
table_open_cache=4000
join_buffer_size = 1M
open_files_limit=10000
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 64M
concurrent_insert = 2
max_connect_errors = 10
net_buffer_length = 16384
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 384
query_cache_limit = 7M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65536
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 16
#skip-networking
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_thread_concurrency=16


performance-schema=0
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M
```

The strangest thing is that when I get an cpu load of 16 - 17, my site stop loading, but others websites on the same server runn very well.
Also, the load NEVER pass of 17 cpu, but the server can handle 48

**I think there is some limit somewhere.**
Can someone make a suggestion?

Comment: PLEASE dont spam tags!!!! Why tag SQLServer and MySQL if you are using `mariadb`

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.